# Running a JS script in a PHP file not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to send a webhook to my discord server when data is inserted into the table, however the function is not being called... Currently it just echos "sendlog()" as shown here: http://prntscr.com/cxqgk5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
 <body>
 <?php
 $token = $_POST["token"];
 $type = $_POST["type"];
 $pid = $_POST["pid"];
 $sid = $_POST["sid"];
 $gid = $_POST["gid"];
 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $players = $_POST["players"];
 $max = $_POST["max"];
 $cdesc = $_POST["cdesc"];
 $sus = $_POST["sus"];

 if($token == 'DS_443'){
  $con =  mysqli_connect("localhost","**","**","**");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo(mysqli_connect_error());
  }
 
  if($type == 'edit' and $players !=NULL and $sid !=NULL){
   $con->query("UPDATE OnlineServers SET ServerCurrent='$players' WHERE ServerID='$sid'");
  } elseif($type == 'remove' and $sid !=NULL){
   $con->query("DELETE FROM OnlineServers WHERE ServerID='$sid'");
  } elseif($type == 'add' and $sid !=NULL and $gid !=NULL and $name!=NULL and $players !=NULL){
   $con->query("INSERT INTO OnlineServers (GameId,GameName,GameMax,ServerCurrent,ServerID,Command) VALUES ('$gid','$name','$max','$players','$sid','TEST')");
 ?>
   sendLog();
 <?php
  } elseif($type == 'call'){
   $con->query("INSERT INTO Calls     (Caller,CallerID,CallID,CallDesc,Suspect,SuspectID,ServerID,GameID) VALUES                  ('$pid','$name','$cdesc','$sus')");
  }        
 } else {
 ?>
  sendLog();
 <?php
 }
?>

<script>
 function sendLog(){ 
  var hookurl =  "webhookurl"
  let tosend = {
  'Server added;',
  'Game Name: ',
  'Game ID: ',
  'Server ID: ',
  },
  var msgJson = {
   "attachments": [
    {
    "color": "#CC09EF",
    "text": tosend,
    "footer": "Infius Game Logs",
    "footer_icon": "http://deersystems.net/assets/images/nfius.png",
    }
   ]
  }
  post(hookurl, msgJson); 
 }
</script>

<script>
 function post(url, jsonmsg){
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  var data = JSON.stringify(jsonmsg);
  xhr.send(data);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(this.status != 200){
    alert("ttt");
   }
  }
 }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java script function should be wrapped inside script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    sendLog();
    </script>
```

OR

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'sendLog();',
     '</script>'
;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have output **sendLog();** whithout **script tag** so, it will be consider normal text. If you want to call that function then you need it between **script tag**.

Also, you should have clean formatting of code. And avoid multiple script tag on same pages. add all js code in single script tag.